# How to fetch image file in java post api which is being sent as formdata in jquery?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have 3 input file fields in my Javascript , the value of which i am sending using formdata in jquery on click of submit button.
I am unable to fetch the file data in my post api which is being called using ajax.

```
"\<div class='row'\>\<div class='col-sm-10'\>\<input type='file' id='myfile_requester1' name='requesterSignatureFile1' accept='image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg' style='box-shadow: 0 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); '/\>\</div\>\</div\>" +
"\<div class='row'\>\<div class='col-sm-10'\>\<input type='file' id='myfile_requester2' name='requesterSignatureFile2' accept='image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg' style='box-shadow: 0 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); '/\>\</div\>\</div\>" +
"\<div class='row'\>\<div class='col-sm-10'\>\<input type='file' id='myfile_requester3' name='requesterSignatureFile3' accept='image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg' style='box-shadow: 0 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); '/\>\</div\>\</div\>"+
"<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-10'><button type='submit' id='submitAttachment'>Submit</button></div>"
```

```
 $('#submitAttachment').click(function() {
 var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("incidentId", jsondata.id );
      var file1 = $('#myfile_requester1').val();
      var file2 =  $('#myfile_requester2').val();
      var file3 =  $('#myfile_requester3').val();
      var file1Val = $('#myfile_requester1').val();
      var file2Val =  $('#myfile_requester2').val();
      var file3Val =  $('#myfile_requester3').val();

        if(file1 != ''){
            file1Val =  $('#myfile_requester1').get(0).files[0];
            formData.append("file1",file1Val);
        }else{
            file1Val = null;
            file1 = null;
        }
        if(file2 != ''){
            file2Val =  $('#myfile_requester2').get(0).files[0];
            formData.append("file2",file2Val);
        }else{
            file2Val = null;
            file2 = null;
        }
        if(file3 != ''){
            file3Val =  $('#myfile_requester3').get(0).files[0];
            formData.append("file3",file3Val);
        }else{
            file3Val = null;
            file3 = null;
        }

         $.ajax({ 
            url : apiUrl + 'updateAfterAttachment', 
            type : 'POST', 
            contentType : "multipart/form-data", 
            data : formData, 
            success : function(data) {
          }, error : function(e) {
            $("#submit_attachment_error").html("An error occured while submitting, please try again").show();           
          } });
}
```

JAVA SNIPPET---

```
@POST @Path("/updateAfterAttachment") @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) public Response createAttachment(@FormDataParam("incidentId") String incidentId, @FormDataParam("file1") InputStream file1, @FormDataParam("file2") InputStream file2, @FormDataParam("file3") InputStream file3) { 
// TO DO
}
```

Solution to fetch file in post api java as my ajax call is not hitting the api.

Comment: This is Javascript, not Java

Comment: the ajax post call which I am doing is to a JAVA post api. below is the skeleton of my API. @tgdavies

Comment: @POST
 @Path("/updateAfterAttachment")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public Response createAttachment(@FormDataParam("incidentId") String incidentId,
   @FormDataParam("file1") String file1,
   @FormDataParam("file2") MultiPart file2, 
   @FormDataParam("file3") MultiPart file3) {
  }

Comment: @GarimaMahajan please update your question with the Java code snippet as well.

Answer (score 0):

You try use case this :

```
 var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            // Create FormData object
            var fileData = new FormData();

            // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }

            // Adding one more key to FormData object
            fileData.append('username', "Dillion");

            $.ajax({
                url: `url`,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                processData: false, // Not to process data
                data: fileData,
                success: function (result) {
                   
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                }
            });
```